# How to configurel Visual Studio in order to run Python3 programs with intellisense

Tags: python-3.x

I have just joined Stackoverflow.  I am a beginner programmer wanting to start programming in Python3.  With a background in VB programming I would like to use an IDE with intellisense to help me start learning to code in Python3.  Visual Studio seems to be ideal for this.  Having installed Visual Studio and installed the Python extension, I tried to code but it gives the following error: command 'python.setInterpreter' not found.  It also gives an output of looking for git.  So I installed the git but it seems to searching for it in the wrong directory path (I don't know how to change this).  Can anyone please help me?  Thanks.

Comment: Did you install python too? Anyway look also at SublimeText3 and VSCode.

Comment: Hi 0 thanks for getting back to me.  Yes, Python 3 is installed and I was using VSCode.  I just now tried SublimeText3 as you suggest using https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0i8JtHHjzu0 but when I tried running the hello world code after I hade saved it, it says that 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.